# Adverb of Frequency for "Sprint"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, british-english, technical, software

Re: Agile Software Development - 
Is there an accepted adverb to describe an activity that happens once per Sprint?

Following the pattern daily, weekly, fortnightly etc, the obvious answer would seem to be "sprintly", but that jars with me (like nails on a blackboard!)

The alternatives are all a little clunky too - "sprint-by-sprint"; "once a sprint"

> "A scrum sprint is a regular, repeatable work cycle in scrum
>   methodology during which work is completed and made ready for review.
>
> Scrum sprints are basic units of development in the scrum methodology.
>   Generally, scrum sprints are less than 30 days long."

(https://www.techopedia.com/definition/13687/scrum-sprint)

Comment: I'd be tempted to use "every sprint", and leave it at that.

Comment: This sounds as if it relates to specific technical terminology.  To me a "scrum" is something in rugby football, and a "sprint" is what a rugby player does when they run with the ball!

Comment: Yeah, I'm wondering why this is tagged British-English, since the "agile programming" terminology for computer projects almost certainly originated in the US.  And this is a question better suited to one of the other groups, such as *Programmers*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about jargon in a specific (computer-related) technology.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i'll check the more technical groups. Tagged as British-English as that's what I use (well, more specifically Hiberno-English!)

Answer (score 0):

Would "per sprint" work? Or "each sprint"?

These 5 tasks must be completed each sprint.

This event happens 5 times per sprint.